# Is there any limit on the number of arguments that redis commands such as ZADD or HMGET can handle?

Tags: redis

I'd like to use single ZADD or HMGET commands instead of a MULTI/EXEC.

Is there any limit on the number of (score, member) tuples that ZADD can handle?

Is there any limit on the number of fields that HMGET can handle?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The theoretical limit is pretty high, but you should design your reads in such a way that you don't reach it. The main reason for keeping reads sanely-sized is to avoid blocking the server for too long.

Several hundreds or thousands should be a good ballpark, but the best thing would be to test it yourself with your code and data.

The hard limits, such as they are, are:

- A hardcoded 1GB for client query buffer (`PROTO_MAX_QUERYBUF_LEN` in server.h)
- The maximum number of arguments is the maximal value of the `int` C data type, which is usually signed and 4 bytes long meaning up to 2,147,483,647.

Comment: Can you tell me more about the theoretical limit you said, please? Is there anything I can read? I'd like to understand when it's best to use ZADD with many (score, member) tuples vs MULTI of ZADD with a single tuple. Same applies to HMGET.

Comment: Editied my answer to include hard limits.