# How many keys can be deleted in a single redis del command?

Tags: redis

I want to delete multiple redis keys using a single delete command on redis client.
Is there any limit in the number of keys to be deleted?

i will be using del key1 key2 ....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42913294/2836621 refers

Answer (score 4):

There's no hard limit on the number of keys, but the query buffer limit does provide a bound. Connections are closed when the buffer hits 1 GB, so practically speaking this is somewhat difficult to hit.

Docs:
https://redis.io/topics/clients

However! You may want to take into consideration that Redis is single-threaded: a time-consuming command will block all other commands until completed. Depending on your use-case this may make a good case for "chunking" up your deletes into groups of, say, 1000 at a time, because it allows other commands to squeeze in between. (Whether or not this is tolerable is something you'll need to determine based on your specific scenario.)